# Site is adding a hashtag to url when resized

Tags: php

Have a site that is throwing a hashtag on the url whenever the site is resized. Theme is saying it's on the hosting side. Hosting is saying it's on the theme developers side.  Personally, I don't think this error would cause a menu to default to an incorrect url but this is the error showing in the logs

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in footer.php

```
                <!-- Copyrights -->
            <div class="copyright">
                <?php 
                    if( mfn_opts_get('footer-copy') ){
                        echo do_shortcode( mfn_opts_get('footer-copy') );
                    } else {
                        echo '&copy; '. date( 'Y' ) .' '. get_bloginfo( 'name' ) .'. All Rights Reserved. 
                    }
                ?>
            </div>

            <?php 
                if( has_nav_menu( 'social-menu-bottom' ) ){

                    // #social-menu
                    mfn_wp_social_menu_bottom();

                } else {

                    $target = mfn_opts_get('social-target') ? 'target="_blank"' : false;

                    echo '<ul class="social">';
                        if( mfn_opts_get('social-skype') ) echo '<li class="skype"><a '.$target.' href="'. mfn_opts_get('social-skype') .'" title="Skype"><i
```

Comment: What does that method do? I think you need to show some more code.

Comment: That seems to be 2 separated problems and none of them seems present in the code snippet. Make sure the line where PHP reports the error is attached.

Comment: If you have something that happens when a page is resized, it's likely to be in your Javascript, not in your PHP. You can't change the URL on a page resize with PHP.

Comment: This is what the hosting company says the snippet is showing lines 93-95.    20150712T065237: highsadityhair.com/index.php 
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in /hermes/waloraweb092/b2912/as.boone1/public_html/wordpress/wp-content/themes/betheme/footer.php on line 94

Comment: So if its triggered on resize and it's javascript related would that be on the hosting or theme side? @MattGibson

Comment: Without seeing any of the code in question (and I agree that there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the snippet you've posted) it's hard to tell. It could be Javascript in the theme triggering an action that causes PHP to do something that ends up changing the URL. But my instincts tell me that Javascript (which would be only in the theme) is the most likely culprit for a problem like this. What do you mean by a "hashtag", by the way? Just a single hash character? Or is there an identifier, too?

Comment: Basically, when you goto highsadityhair.com when you resize the window or look at it on a mobile and click the menu the url changes to highsadityhair.com/# @MattGibson

Comment: So, what you actually mean is that when the small ("Hamburger"-style) menu is displayed rather than the full-width menu, it doesn't work. This does seem to be the case. The element in question has this HTML: `<a class="responsive-menu-toggle " href="#"><i class="icon-menu"></i></a>`. I'd expect JavaScript to have been loaded to actually do something, rather leaving you at the `/#` link (the `href="#"` is a common idiom for "a click on this will actually be handled by JavaScript".) As to what's broken, you'd probably need an actual programmer to look into it properly.